# Select dentro de for

Tags: python, select, lógica

Seguinte, minha dúvida é mais sobre lógica mesmo..
Eu tenho um script em python no qual eu uso o psycopg2 para realizar buscas no banco de dados. Porém eu preciso fazer isso dentro de um for.
Eu tenho plena noção que fazer uma busca dentro de um for pode afetar e muito no desempenho do código, além de ficar algo 'feio'. 
Já pensei em outras soluções como por exemplo trazer uma query geral e trabalhar com 1 laço dentro de outro para substituir o select mas creio que isso me daria um processamento alto do mesmo jeito....
 Quando eu me deparo com uma situação dessa qual a melhor saida para evitar um select a cada laço do for?

```
for busca_filas in rows_sip:
            if busca_filas[1] == 'QUEUE':
                dict_filas.update({"fisico": busca_filas[2]})
                dict_filas.update({"virtual": busca_filas[4]})
                cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM queue_members where queue_name = '" + busca_filas[2] + "';")
                busca_ramais_filas = cursor.fetchall()
                for item_ramais_filas in busca_ramais_filas:
                    dict_detalhe_filas.update({'nome_fila': item_ramais_filas[0]})
                    dict_detalhe_filas.update({'ramal': item_ramais_filas[3]})
                    dict_detalhe_filas.update({'pausado': item_ramais_filas[4]})
                    list_detalhe_filas.append(dict_detalhe_filas)
                    dict_detalhe_filas = {}
                dict_filas.update({'ramais': list_detalhe_filas})
                list_filas.append(dict_filas)
                list_detalhe_filas = []
                dict_filas = {}
```

Criei esse código de exemplo apenas para vocês entenderem como está meu código.

Comment: O que você poderia fazer, é deixar o SQL trabalhar de forma relacional como ele foi otimizado pra fazer, ou seja, trazendo tudo que você precisa da query de uma vez so, ou seja, fazer um join com essa queue_members, e trazer as colunas que você precisa, ao invés de usar esse asterisco, ordena a query de forma que os ramais fiquem sempre abaixo dos nomes certos, e faça um único for, usando condicional para saber se foi mudado de nome. Acho que fica mais eficiente.

Comment: Nossa, algo tão basico.. kkkkkk. Entendi sua ideia e na verdade da pra melhorar ainda mais, a ponto de eu conseguir tirar o select de dentro do for. Vou refazer esse código e postar aqui pra galera que tiver alguma dúvida parecida

Comment: Isso mesmo, essa é a idéia, dá uma olhada na minha resposta :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça a query contendo tudo que precisa de uma vez só.

```
Select [coluna que tem o valor 'Queue'], 
       [Coluna que tem o valor de 'Fisico'], 
       [Coluna que tem o valor de 'Virtual'], 
       queue_name, 
       nome_fila, 
       ramal, 
       pausado
From [tabela princial] A
Left join queue_members B on B.queue_name = A.[coluna que tem o nome]
Where [coluna que tem o valor 'Queue'] = 'Queue'
Order by queue_name
```

Depois de fazer a query, faça o for nela.

```
//declare uma variavel para o nome. Ex.: _nome
for busca_filas in rows_sip:
            if _nome == "":
                _nome = busca_filas[3]                
            elif _nome != busca_filas[3]:
                _nome = busca_filas[3]
                dict_filas.update({'ramais': list_detalhe_filas})
                list_filas.append(dict_filas)
                list_detalhe_filas = []
                dict_filas = {}

            dict_filas.update({"fisico": busca_filas[1]})
            dict_filas.update({"virtual": busca_filas[2]})  
            dict_detalhe_filas.update({'nome_fila': item_ramais_filas[4]})
            dict_detalhe_filas.update({'ramal': item_ramais_filas[5]})
            dict_detalhe_filas.update({'pausado': item_ramais_filas[6]})
            list_detalhe_filas.append(dict_detalhe_filas)
            dict_detalhe_filas = {}
```

Me perdoe, eu não conheço python então, não consigo escrever os condicionais direito.

Se você puder separar em métodos, dá para não repetir código onde preenche os Ramais.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: obrigado pela correção @jsbueno :-)

Comment: dei uma simplificada no código, mas acho que você entendeu a idéia né?

Comment: Eu vou marcar como certa pq vc se esforçou para me ajudar e tal. eu entendi sua logicoa acima e realmente o código funciona. Mas o meu problema é que no meu código eu tenho 50mil 'for' porque eu preciso fazer select dentro de select para montar varios JSON e isso esta dando uma ferrada no processamento do server e eu queria ideias para sair desses varios laços de repetição...

Comment: Enfim, estudando des de ontem sobre o assunto eu cheguei a conclusão de que eu devo rever todo o script que eu montei

Comment: Bom, independente do tamanho do problema, tente manter esse tipo de raciocínio em mente, tente deixar o máximo possível de consultas juntas, para tirar proveito da otimização do banco. :-) boa sorte!